# Why are there 17 native segwit versions?

Tags: segregated-witness

Given that computers operate in binary, we often see various limits and scopes come in powers of 2. How come there are not sixteen (0–15) but seventeen (0–16) different native segwit versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Segwit has 17 versions, because *[Script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Constants)* defines the constants `OP_0`–`OP_16` explicitly, while any other numbers would need to be added to the output script with `OP_PUSHDATA`.

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Can OP_1NEGATE be an 18th SegWit version?